# Including multiple views overwrites content of other included views

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have various templates like `sms.birthday` and `sms.account-created`. They all inherit from a base view `layouts.sms`. On one of the admin pages, I wanted to show a preview of these views by including them with some dummy data. However, when including the views, the first one that is included overwrites the sections of all other views.

```
// layouts.sms
@yield('sms.content')
```

```
// sms.birthday
@extends('layouts.sms')

@section('sms.content')
    Happy birthday
@stop
```

```
// sms.account-created
@extends('layouts.sms')

@section('sms.content')
    Account created
@stop
```

```
// admin page
@include('sms.birthday')
@include('sms.account-created')
```

Expected results on admin page:

```
Happy birthday
Account created
```

Actual results on admin page:

```
Happy birthday
Happy birthday
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `@stop`, using `@overwrite` solves my issue.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1058#issuecomment-17194530